# Update the input next to any select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this PHP script that generates a form:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "<tr class='vraagrij'><td><select name='select" . $i . "'><option>1</option>  <option>2</option></select></td><td><input type='text' value='Test' name='select" . $i . "'></td><td><select name='selectdos" . $i . "'><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td></tr>";
}
```

What I need is to update the text in the input field of a specific row ONCE, whenever any element in that row has changed. So far I came up with this (I use css('color', 'yellow') for convenience and to easily see the behavior). But it only updates the changed element, and only once (since changed is set to 1, so I would need a new 'changed' per row, but I don't know how many rows there are going to be).

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var changed = 0;

    $('.vraagrij').children().change(function(e) {
        if(clicked = 0)
        {
            var $parent = $(e.target).parent();
            var $kids = $parent.children("input");
            $kids.css('color', 'yellow');
            changed = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `if(clicked = 0)` a typo error or what? it should be `if(clicked == 0)` right?

Comment: I think it should even be `changed == 0`, or else the variable wouldn't be read anywhere?

Comment: clicked is the same as changed, and is indeed a typo, it should've been clicked == 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1: Per row closure

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6dx6/)

What you could do is use the [each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to create a closure for each row, in this case each row has its own changed variable.

Also, rather than bind directly to the input element you can use the [on() jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the event listener indirectly.

**Note:** The inputs are not children directly off the row element so swap [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as well.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // Using the each function to create
  // a row specific closure
  $('.vraagrij').each(function() {

    // Track the state per row
    var changed = false

        // Create a variable to reference the
        // row directly in the change listener
      , $row = $(this);

    // Use event delegation to bind to all
    // descendant selects of the row efficiently
    $row.on("change", "select", function(e) {

      // Make sure the following only runs once
      // per row
      if(!changed) {
        changed = true;

        // Do something to the input, changing
        // color for testing purposes
        var $kids = $row.find("input");
        $kids.css('color', 'yellow');

      }
    });

  });

});
```

## Method 2: DOM query / traversal

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6dx6/4/)

This method uses the state of the DOM to track the changed state:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Again using event delegation to bind events
  // efficiently
  $(".vraagrij").on("change", "select", function(e) {

    // Collect the parent row
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

    // Check if it has already got the
    // changed class
    if(!$row.hasClass("changed")) {

      // Add the changed class in to track
      // the state and prevent this being
      // run again for the same row
      $row
        .addClass("changed")

        // Perform the action for the changed
        // select
        .find("input")
          .css("color", "yellow");
    }
  });

});
```

## Method 3: Use the one method

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6dx6/3/)

The [one method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) handles the event once.

**Update** including the great advice from [billyonecan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087721/billyonecan) to use `closest("tr")` instead of `parents("tr:eq(0)")` or `parents("tr").first()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Again using event delegation to bind events
  // efficiently, this time using the one method
  $(".vraagrij").one("change", "select", function(e) {

    // Perform the action for the changed
    // select
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input").css("color", "yellow");
  });

});
```

Comment: +1 for the third method, probably the best solution here. You could use `$(this).closest('tr')` by the way, instead of `.parents('tr:eq(0)')`

Comment: Both the `select` and `input` elements have a relative attribute - they both use the same `name`. There's no need to use `.find()`, `.closest()` (or `.parent()`, as some of the other answers here are using).

Comment: Hi James, one of the selects has the same name, your answer will not work for the other select in the row, nor will ensure a single change event **per row** as the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new class at every changed tr:

```
$('.vraagrij').on("change","input,select",function(e){
    $parent_tr=$(this).closest('tr');
    if (!$parent_tr.hasClass('changed'))
    {
      $parent_tr.addClass('changed');
      $parent_tr.find("input").css('color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpnfc/1/)

Comment: This wont prevent the handler from being called the second time around. The not() filter is applied before the event handler is attached, it is not evaluated again each time the event is triggered. Add a console.log("changed") in that listener, you will see that it keeps getting triggered.

Comment: You're right, I suppose I wrote it thinking in the .change() event. Edited to work as intended

Answer (score 0):

```
if(clicked = 0)
```

it should be

```
if(clicked == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `clicked` or `changed` are for, but your `if` statement is currently *setting* the value of `clicked` to 0, and not comparing it with 0. You should use `===` in this case:

```
if(clicked === 0)
```

You should also make use of jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler.

Your code does a lot of unnecessary things. You should make use of the CSS [starts-with selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (`^=`):

```
// Select with a name beginning with "select", e.g. "select3"
$('.vraagrij').on('change', 'select[name^="select"]', function() {
    if(clicked === 0)
    {
        var
            name = $(this).attr('name'), // "select3", for instance
            $input = $('input[name="' + name + '"]') // input[name="select3"]
        ;
        $input.css('color', 'yellow');
        changed = 1;
    }
});
```